# Rust AWS SDK: create keys with IAM role on the fly?

Tags: rust, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-rust

I'm trying to create temporary(?) credentials using an IAM role. From what I learned in the package's GitHub issues, they implemented the feature for Rust but I just can't figure where it is.

The equivalent code in NodeJS is:

```
import * as aws from 'aws-sdk'

ecsCredentials = new aws.ECSCredentials()

await ecsCredentials.getPromise()
aws.config.credentials = ecsCredentials
```

Comment: How have you tried to convert it to Rust and/or what is the problem with your Rust implementation of your JS? People are happy to help with issues you face, but aren't willing just to port something between languages for you.

Comment: @JeremyMeadows I guess my request really wasn't clear, I edited the OP. Anyway what I meant is that I learned that the Rust implementation exists in a library by Amazon but I just can't find it / figure how to use it.

Comment: They have an [`aws-sdk-iam` crate on crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/aws-sdk-iam), is that what you're looking for? They have a list of other crates on [their website](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-rust/) if that's not the correct one.

Comment: @JeremyMeadows looks like what I need but I can't find usage examples.. I think what I need to use is `aws_sdk_iam::client::fluent_builders::CreateAccessKey` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing:

```rust
use aws_config::ecs::EcsCredentialsProvider;

// When run in AWS, this uses the execution role to create temporary credentials.
let credentials_provider_builder = EcsCredentialsProvider::builder();
let creadentials_provider = credentials_provider_builder.build();
let credentials = creadentials_provider.credentials();

// Convert to Config object and connect.
let conf = aws_config::from_env().credentials_provider(credentials).region("us-east-1").load().await;
let conf = Config::new(&conf);
let client = Client::from_conf(conf);
```